# Using statement for directory search or Ldap functionality in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am very new to VB.net. Can i use the USING Statement for calling the Directory Entry and Searcher like the below.

```
Using entry As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://xxx.com.my"))
        entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Delegation
        entry.Username = username
        entry.Password = password

        Using searcher As New DirectorySearcher(entry)
            searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.OneLevel
            Try
                Dim results As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne

                success = Not (results Is Nothing)
            Catch ex As Exception
                success = False
                WriteToFile("ValidateADLogin error : " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry` and `System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher` both inherit from `System.ComponentModel.Component`, which implements the `IDisposable` interface. So yes, you can use both of them in a Using statement (`IDisposable` is required for this).

Normally the compiler will issue an error if no class in the inheritance chain implements `IDisposable`.

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher